# Unset inside array_walk_recursive not working

Tags: php, arrays

```
  array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$val, $key){
    if($val == 'smth'){
      unset($val);          // <- not working, unset($key) doesn't either
      $var = null;          // <- setting it to null works
    }
  });

  print_r($arr);
```

I don't want it to be null, I want the element out of the array completely. Is this even possible with array_walk_recursive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: unset elements with 'array\_walk\_recursive'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235901/php-unset-elements-with-array-walk-recursive)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `array_walk_recursive` here but you can write your own function. It's easy:

```
function array_unset_recursive(&$array, $remove) {
    $remove = (array)$remove;
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (in_array($value, $remove)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            array_unset_recursive($value, $remove);
        }
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
array_unset_recursive($arr, 'smth');
```

or remove several values:

```
array_unset_recursive($arr, ['smth', 51]);
```

Answer (score 5):

`unset($val)` will only remove the local `$val` variable.

There is no (sane) way how you can remove an element from the array inside `array_walk_recursive`. You probably will have to write a custom recursive function to do so.

Comment: I thought of that, but what if the array has more than 2 levels?

Comment: @JohnSmith Just noticed that too :(

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @dfsq is correct but this function doesn't remove empty array. So you can end up with Tree of empty array, which is not what is expected in most cases.
I used this modified function instead:

```
public function array_unset_recursive(&$array, $remove) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $arraySize = $this->array_unset_recursive($value, $remove);
            if (!$arraySize) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        } else if (in_array($key, $remove, true)){
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return count($array);
}
```