# Remove array items from nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I try to remove a key / value from a `$_GET` string in case a given trigger string matches.

If the get was one level array that's simple to solve it, but because the `$_GET` can contains nested arrays, I have a litle problem.

Let's say I have the following `$_GET` string:

```
?nikos=vasilis&merianos=nikos&greece[corfu]=ionian%20islands&greece[corfu]=west%20greece&another_var[l1][l2][]=trigger-1&another_var[l1][l2][trigger-2]=value
```

that translated into the following by using `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [nikos] => vasilis
    [merianos] => nikos
    [greece] => Array
        (
            [corfu] => west greece
        )

    [another_var] => Array
        (
            [l1] => Array
                (
                    [l2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => trigger-1
                            [trigger-2] => value
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

In order to match the trigger string, that in my case is the `trigger-1` and `trigger-2` i use the following code:

```
$iterator  = new \RecursiveArrayIterator( $_GET );
$recursive = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator( $iterator, \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
$triggers  = array(
    'trigger-1',
    'trigger-2'
);

foreach ( $recursive as $key => $value ) {
    if ( in_array( $key, $triggers ) || in_array( $value, $triggers ) ) {
        echo "I found it";
    }
}
```

What I need, is when the trigger matches to remove te given key from the current itterated array.

So, what is the best way to perform this action ?

**- UPDATE 1 -**

I just try this, but strill doesn't work:

```
$iterator->getInnerIterator()->offsetUnset( $key );
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Using `unset($key)` no ? what is the problem ?

Comment: I have try that but didn't work out. Also, unset key of what ? From `$recursive` ? Also the key referes to the current array in recursion.

Comment: Define a var : `$get = $_GET;` then remove using `unset($get[$key]);` and use $get after.

Comment: @VincentDecaux thanks for your reply, but this doesn't work too. I just try it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

People who recommend to unset $key, you must read manual.
Unsetting $key just unset variable $key - not array element!
If you want to unset array element you must apply unset to them.
In this case:

```
unset($recursive[$key])
```

Comment: As you read in the documentation this is a NOT TO USE. This producing the following : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type RecursiveIteratorIterator as array in ..../core.php on line 89.

Comment: Oh, i missed that is not array

Comment: @MerianosNikos I read a little about this problem and seems were no way to delete element in recursive iterator. But you can do this without iterator, check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150726/unset-inside-array-walk-recursive-not-working Hope it help you

Answer (score -1):

You can use in loop to remove key item `unset($key)`

Comment: It did not work, because you unset variable $key : ) If you want unset array element then do ``unset($recursive[$key] )``