# filter multi dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a five dimensional array ,

I would like to filter items in a different levels ,

every item that it's `url` equals to `"MUSET REMOVED"` should be removed .

```php
    $menu = array(
        "System" => array(
            "VisibleName" => "System",
            "Children" => array(
                "Access" => array(
                    "VisibleName" => "Access",
                    "Url"=>"/sth",
                    "Children" => array(
                        "Groups" => array(
                            "VisibleName" => "Groups",
                            "Url" => "/Groups"
                        ),
                        "LockoutTable" => array(
                            "VisibleName" => "LockoutTable",
                            "Url" => "MUST REMOVED"
                        ),
                        "Password" => array(
                            "VisibleName" => "Password",
                            "Url" => "MUST REMOVED"
                        ),
                    
                    ),
                "users" => array(
                    "VisibleName" => "users",
                    "Url"=>"MUST REMOVED",
                    "Children" => array()
                ),
                "roles" => array(
                    "VisibleName" => "Access",
                    "Url"=>"/roles",
                    "Children" => array()
                    )
                ),
            )
        ),
    );

    $filtered_menu = array();

    foreach ($menu as $level_one_k => $level_one_v) {

        $level_two_filtered=array();

        foreach($level_one_v as $level_two_k=>$level_two_v){
           // i dont know How to continue this
           // it must filter every item that its Url == "MUST REMOVED"
        }

        $filtered_menu[$level_one_k]=$level_two_filtered;
    }
```

I don't know How to handle filter of such complicated array .

the expected result would be like this:

```php
    $menu = array(
        "System" => array(
            "VisibleName" => "System",
            "Children" => array(
                "Access" => array(
                    "VisibleName" => "Access",
                    "Url"=>"/sth",
                    "Children" => array(
                        "Groups" => array(
                            "VisibleName" => "Groups",
                            "Url" => "/Groups"
                        ),
                    
                    ),

                "roles" => array(
                    "VisibleName" => "Access",
                    "Url"=>"/roles",
                    "Children" => array()
                    )
                ),
            )
        ),
    );
```

---

---

just some bela bela to pass question
just some bela bela to pass question
just some bela bela to pass question

Comment: What should be removed? Only the entry with the key url or the parent array? Please show the array you expect as a result.

Comment: parent array must be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I did it with this

with help of [Unset inside array_walk_recursive not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150726/unset-inside-array-walk-recursive-not-working)

```php
function array_unset_recursive(&$array)
{
    global $aclObj;
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {

      if (is_array($value)) {
        if (isset($value['Url']) && !empty($value['Url'])) {
          if(condition){
            unset($array[$key]);
          }
        } else {
          array_unset_recursive($value);
        }
      }
    }

}
```